# В чем проблема?увеличиваются элементы!

Tags: unity3d

При уходе со сцены я переношу 2 UI элемента в другой канвас с DontDestroyOnLoad(),при переходе на другую сцену я возвращаю эти UI элементы в основной канвас сцены,только проблема в том,что они становятся слишком большие.Как это поправить?[Вот что получается](https://i.stack.imgur.com/irZE8.jpg)

Comment: Прикрепите код, как вы "прикрепляете" эти элементы к другому canvas.

Comment: Размеры или типы канвасов разные, и при переносе у вас scale или размеры у элементов зашкаливают

Answer (score 0):

При переносе вы используете первую перегрузку метода [transform.SetParent(Transform parent)](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Transform.SetParent.html).
Там есть ещё одна - она принимает bool worldPositionStays - нужно ли сохранять размеры или отскейлить согласно новому родителю. Вам требуется использовать там false -  `transform.SetParent(parent, false)`